# Error creating bean with name 'countriesDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, spring-mvc

Im trying to start Tomcat but when I try start it im getting the following error

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'countriesDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.fexco.helloworld.web.util.CustomHibernateDaoSupport.anyMethodName(org.hibernate.SessionFactory); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

CountriesDao

```
package com.fexco.helloworld.web.dao;

import com.fexco.helloworld.web.model.Countries;

public interface CountriesDao {


void save(Countries countries);
void update(Countries countries);
void delete(Countries countries);
Countries findByCountry(String country);
}
```

The start of CountriesDaoImpl

```
package com.fexco.helloworld.web.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.fexco.helloworld.web.model.Countries;
import com.fexco.helloworld.web.util.CustomHibernateDaoSupport;

@Repository("countriesDao")
public class CountriesDaoImpl extends CustomHibernateDaoSupport implements CountriesDao{

public void save(Countries countries){
    getHibernateTemplate().save(countries);
}
......
}
```

Some of Application-config.xml

```
<bean id="countriesDao" class="com.fexco.helloworld.web.dao.CountriesDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
.... 
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.fexco.helloworld.web" />

<bean 
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

CustomHibernateDaoSupport class

```
package com.fexco.helloworld.web.util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;

public abstract class CustomHibernateDaoSupport extends HibernateDaoSupport
{    
@Autowired
public void anyMethodName(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
{
    setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
}
}
```

Is the error because CountriesDaoImpl isnt really implementing CountriesDao?
Does anyone know how to solve this error?

Thanks

Comment: The question is slightly confusing. You are talking about CountriesDAO but the code of the DAOImpl is CustomerDAOImpl. Also the exception clearly says that the SessionFactory that you are using from Hibernate is not able to be autowired. If i see the code you are mixing annotations and xml configurations. Try to stick with one. Check whether you have the proper setter defined in the DAO for the sessionFactory to inject. Also please edit and place the appropriate code of the CountriesDAOImpl. The error seems to be happening in the CustomHibernateDaoSupport, please paste that code a s well.

Comment: Sorry about that, i also have a customerDao and customerDaoImpl... I have changed it and put up the CustomHibernateDaoSupport class as well. Sorry im new to this so trying to learn as much as i can, so would t be better to take away the xml configurations so because the annotations does it anyway?

Comment: Please take a look at this documentation to properly configure and autowire the hibernate session factory http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-session-factory-setup

Comment: I have solve this problem. I did not have my web.xml pointing to my application-context.xml so that it could not find my hibernate.xml and DataSource.xml files

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do not have session factory defined in your dao Implementation class. You should defined one if not already defined And avoid using both configurations It will messed up things i.e

```
            @Autowired
        @Qualifier("sessionFactory")
        public void seSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

            this.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        }
```